# PDO SHOW TABLES has strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have such a code:

```
$tableName = "TableThatDoesNotExist";
$s = $db->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE ':tableName'");
$s->bindParam(':tableName', $tableName);
$s->execute();
$row = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo count($row);
```

And for some strange reason `echo count($row);` produces `1`, even though I do not have such a table. What is more strange is that if a table exists, then `echo empty($row);` will produce `true`. So, what's wrong with that?

Comment: this assumes your DB user has correct privilege to use show.

Comment: what do you mean by "this" in your comment? I said quite a lot, so I can not figure out what you mean.

Comment: I mean your database user had to have the correct privileges to the database etc., https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html , as stated at the bottom it doesn't give you an error if you don't. `If you have no privileges for a base table or view, it does not show up in the output from ...`  Also I see an issue with casing I always do my tables lowercase and with `'_'` instead of space because of that.  `TableThatDoesNotExist` vs `table_that_does_not_exist` Which is easier to read.

Comment: Not to mention I am not 100% sure that bind works on Show tables because it's a whole different syntax then `column LIKE :value`, have you tried the show query against the database, in like PhpMyAdmin?  Then you will know your query is good. And get it working then work backwards and see where it breaks.